# Click event is not working most of the time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build a simple game in html using jquery. The game concept is there will be coins dropping from top to bottom. user has to collect the coin by clicking or tapping on it. I animate the dropping box using Animate but when i tried to click on it, not working most of the time. Please help me how to fix this on both desktop and mobile as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Snow Falling
  function fallingSnow() {
    //Adjust the Screen Areas
    $('#site').width(0);
    $('#site').height(0);
    $('#site').width($(window).width());
    $('#site').height($(window).height());

    var $snowflakes = $(),
      createSnowflakes = function() {
        $('.snowflakes').remove();
        var qt = 5;
        for (var i = 0; i < qt; ++i) {
          var $snowflake = $('<div class="snowflakes"></div>');
          $snowflake.css({
            'left': (Math.random() * $('#site').width()) + 'px',
            'top': (-Math.random() * $('#site').height()) + 'px'
          });
          // add this snowflake to the set of snowflakes
          $snowflakes = $snowflakes.add($snowflake);
        }
        $('#snowZone').prepend($snowflakes);
      },

      runSnowStorm = function() {
        $snowflakes.each(function() {

          var singleAnimation = function($flake) {
            var speed = Math.random(); // 1 is Faster 0 is Slower
            // 0.6 is Slowest, 0.8 is Normal, 1 is Fastest
            var p = 0;

            //Adjust Points and Speed Below
            if (speed > 0.8) {
              speed = 1;
              p = '100';
            } else if (speed > 0.6 && speed < 0.8) {
              speed = 0.8;
              p = '080';
            } else if (speed < 0.6) {
              speed = 0.6;
              p = '060';
            }

            speed = 0.1;

            $flake.attr("class", 'snowflakes');
            $flake.addClass('p' + p);

            $flake.animate({
              //top: "500px",
              top: $('#site').height(),
              opacity: "1",
              //}, Math.random()*-2500 + 3000, function(){
            }, 0.9 * -2500 + 6000, function() {
              //}, speed*-2500 + 9000, function(){
              // this particular snow flake has finished, restart again
              $flake.css({
                'left': (Math.random() * $('#site').width()) + 'px',
                'top': (-Math.random() * $('#site').height()) + 'px',
                'opacity': 0.5
              });
              singleAnimation($flake, speed);

            });
          };
          singleAnimation($(this), 0.1);
        });
      };

    createSnowflakes();
    runSnowStorm();
  }
  fallingSnow();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    fallingSnow();
  });








  curScore = 0;
  $('.score').text(curScore);
  $('body').on('click tap', '.snowflakes', function() {
    curScore++;
    $('.score').text(curScore);
    console.log('Clicked ' + $(this).attr('class') + ' ' + Math.random());
  });













});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.snowflakes {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#site {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: grey;
}

.snowflakes.p100 {
  background: green;
}

.snowflakes.p080 {
  background: blue;
}

.snowflakes.p060 {
  background: pink;
}

#site .score {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 400;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="site">
  <div id="snowZone"></div>
  <p class="score">20</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Works really well for me on Chrome.

Comment: Please try this URL on mobile and Desktop. its not actually picking the Click event because of the Animate Function. please help!!!
https://orangerie.ae/test/

Comment: @Najeeb did you have the chance to test the version I added below?

Comment: Yes @SaschaM78 it works great and you saved me as well :) Thanks alot. Nice thinking.

Comment: @Najeeb then I would appreciate if you would mark my answer as solution ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the *"click"* and *"tap"* events, I would recommend to use *"mousedown"* and *"touchstart*". At least the **click** event requires **both mousedown and mouseup** event to happen on the same element. In case you click a specific moving element, the `mousedown` event is triggered on this element but when releasing the mouse again while the target element moved away from the click position the `mouseup` fires on the body element or whatever happens to be behind the element so you won't have a completed `click` event on the element.

In your code this would require the following change:

```
$("body").on("mousedown touchstart", ".snowflakes", function() {
    curScore++;
    $(".score").text(curScore);
    console.log("Clicked " + $(this).attr("class") + " " + Math.random());
 });
```

Here is a changed version of your code to test the change: [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/KYrYQe)